# Adding UIPageView as a portion of a screen

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

Pretty new to iOS development and curious whether something is possible and if so the best want to do it.

I'd like to make a UIPageViewController be a portion of the screen.  I.e., I want to have a menu bar, perhaps some additional controls and then place the page view controller on a portion of that page (so the menu bar isn't part of the page turning control).  In other words, a UIPageView that acts like a scrollView that doesn't take up the whole screen.

Acceptable design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is possible, and the implementation is very easy.

**Steps** (implemented in XCode 6 using Storyboards)

1. Begin with an empty view controller.

[image: empty view controller]

2. Add a Container View from the object library on the right. The Container View may automatically embed in a regular View Controller, in which case you can just delete the View Controller because we want to embed a Page View Controller.

[image: view controller with container view]

3. Select a Page View Controller from the object library on the right, and place it wherever you want in your Storyboard.

[image: view controller and page view controller]

4. Ctrl Click + drag from the Container View to the Page View Controller, and select embed from the menu that appears. The Page View Controller should automatically resize itself to be the same size as the Container View in the original View Controller.

[image: page view controller embed step]

Answer (score 1):

A nice example from apple developer sample code: [PageControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html). Implemented with `UIScrollView` and `UIPageControl`.

Also you may want to create a new iOS project with template "Page-Based Application". The template code is implemented with `UIPageViewController`.

Both implementation employ View Controller Containment.

BTW: the is no UIPageView, only `UIPageControl` or `UIPageViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Below link for uipageviewcontroller Tutorial

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

U can Try uiview for pageturning not uiviewcontroller

u can add uiview to uiviewcontroller.

like [Self.view addSubview:youruiview];

and Remove uiview controller like [youruiview removefromsuperview];

Thanks..!

Comment: I think the part that I am getting stuck on is controlling the UIPageController function.  In other words, I can create a UIPageController, I can throw its view into a subview of my page, I just don't know how to access the functionality of the pageViewController as if the parent controller was a UIPageViewController as opposed to a straight up UIViewController.